# How to configure GSuit for external server email accounts

Tags: vps, g-suite

I have configured Gsuit for emails with single gsuit user and another of external server user (non-gmail account).

For it I have created host that point to IP address of server and then configure route for a server based single email address like abc@example.com.

Server configuration:

`MX 1  aspmx.l.google.com.`

Gsuit Configuration like:

- Inbound/outbound
- Single email address (abc@example.com)
- Change route to VPS Server

[image]

But no emails are being sent/ received at server.

Is there any remaining configuration?

Answer (score 0):

The technology called Dual Delivery OR Split Delivery. When emails are addressed to email addresses that are not found in one mail server it will send its delivery to another mail server and even can split them.

For example
domain.com has default mx record set to gsuite. User abc@domain.com is set under google apps & user xyz@domain.com under vps server. Now if someone send mail to xyz@domain.com which is configured under google apps, so the first request transferred to gsuite but gsuite cannot found that email within organization so it will push the request to vps server and will deliver the mail in its inbox.

Google Apps also offer dual delivery but unfortunately its available for Google Apps for Work account only. Alternatively try Zoho is offering it for all type of accounts so you still have chance to get it done via zoho.

Solution

```
Set up your domain MX record to Zoho
Configure delivery as per guideline mentioned here
```

https://www.zoho.com/mail/help/adminconsole/email-routing.html

If you would like to keep google apps account as primary then setup instructions can be found here https://support.google.com/a/answer/96855?hl=en

Comment: I have already configured split delivery but no success as indicated in above image

Comment: If send me info at 5r and will get it fix